# How do I remove unwanted commits form another branch for PR

Tags: git, branch, commit

I've done a stupid thing. I branched from branch A, made changes on a new branch, pushed and made a PR into branch B (also bringing a lot of unwanted commits into it).

My problem is that I need to get rid of several commits only on a branch where I made changes but I have no idea how to do it. There are many info on how to get rid of the last commit, but in my case it's exactly the last commit I want to leave on the branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new branch from branchB

```
git checkout branchB
git checkout -b newB
```

Then get the changes you need from your last branch (lets call it `branchFromA` here)

```
git cherry-pick branchFromA
```

(this last [command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) picked only the last commit from that branch*, like you wanted)

And it will now be a simple fast-forward merge to branchB :

```
git checkout branchB
git merge newB
```

Alternatively for this last phase, since you seem to use PRs, just push `newB` to the remote, make a new PR from `newB` to `branchB`, and finally cancel your `branchFromA` to `branchB` PR.

---

*often used with an explicit commit reference, but you can feed it a branch or tag name, and the commit that ref is pointing to is taken as target for the cherry-pick

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you!